# One way Input Textbox - text data transfer from main App file to a PopUp Window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a main Application file opening a Pop Up window and I do need to (One way only) transfer TEXT String data from a Input Text box to a text box in the popup. As can be seen that is already done for a userID (Number) which gets the data from a Xml file and this works well! yet it seem to be more difficult with text ??? well I have tried it over and over but unfortunately it wont work! So any suggestions or help with that would be very much appreciated! regards aktell

**Main App. file:**

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[

import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

private function Info():void {

var winOne:DialogOne = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, DialogOne, true) as DialogOne;

PopUpManager.centerPopUp(winOne);

 // Transfering userID to PopUp Window.
winOne.txtUserIDNumber = parseFloat(userWebID.text);
}
]]>
</fx:Script>

 <mx:Button
click="Info()"/>

<mx:TextInput
id="userWebID"
text="{selectedDataOne.@userID}"
/>
```

**DialogOne Pop Up Window file:**

```
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[

[Bindable]
public var txtUserIDNumber:Number;

import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:TextInput
text="{txtUserIDNumber}"
/>
```

Comment: it works exactly the same way as Number(just use String type), what error do you get?

Comment: You are so right! even so I have tried all afternoon including that yet I believe I must had a typo or else restarted and it worked! most appreciated thanks regards aktell